# Is there a good alternative to Primefaces For Django?

Tags: django, web, primefaces

I'm a big fan of Django. And i get used to use Primefaces for Java EE applications. So is there a good alternative to Primefaces or is it possible to use Primefaces components with Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this app which puts PrimeUI (not all of PrimeFaces) into Django: 
https://bitbucket.org/livioribeiro/django-primeui